# Redshift / Postgresql query multiple tables faster than Natural Full Join

Tags: query-performance, join, postgresql-performance, redshift

I have been given a requirement to query 8(+) different Redshift tables and return some of the fields where email = provided email address.

Current implementation:

```
(select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyA) companyA 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyB) companyB 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyC) companyC 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyD) companyD 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyE) companyE 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyF) companyF 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyG) companyG 
 natural full join
 (select product_name, email, firstname, lastname, accountid, phone, 
   from companyH) companyH 
 where email = 'foobybar@barfoo.com';
```

The problem with this approach is that each of these tables are quite large and so the query can take 45+ seconds. To make it worse, I will eventually need to implement a one to many join on "accountid" to 8 account tables to grab some fields there.

And... my boss wants all of this to happen in less than 5 seconds... I don't think that will be possible, but I wanted to know if there were things I can do to speed this search up as much as possible?

**Solution:**
As many people pointed out, 'UNION ALL' (when used correctly) sped it up by quite a bit! I still have a bunch of joins, but brought the time down by a lot. Here is the final solution:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
     SELECT usr.product_name, acc.product_loc, acc.phone, usr.email, usr.firstname, usr.lastname, usr.accountid,  
       FROM companyA usr
         JOIN companyA_accounts acc ON usr.accountid = acc.id
     UNION ALL 
    SELECT usr.product_name, acc.product_loc, acc.phone, usr.email, usr.firstname, usr.lastname, usr.accountid,  
      FROM companyB usr
         JOIN companyB_accounts acc ON usr.accountid = acc.id
     /* UNION ALL SELECT repeated for the rest of the tables */
  ) alltables
 WHERE alltables.email =  'foobybar@barfoo.com';
```

Comment: Don't you want a `UNION` rather than a join?

Comment: I just tried with ```UNION``` and it took 1m23s, the ```NATURAL FULL JOIN``` took 1m3s

Comment: What about UNION ALL?

Comment: Well, a UNION and a FULL JOIN are doing two completely different things. And you probably want a UNION ALL anyway. And please do not add the `postgresql` tag. Redshift pretends to be Postgres but it's not. And performance related questions are highly product specific.

Comment: @RonJohn ```UNION ALL``` just clocked 1m55s